# BCryptPasswordEncoder IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Соответствии с [этим](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/) гайдом сделал себе регистрацию на сайте. Все прекрасно работало до вчерашнего вечера когда в какой то момент (вот это пропустил , каюсь) запуск Томката начал выдавать ошибку а весь проект не отображаться.

Методом не хитрого закоментирования кода было вычислено что проблема в xml конфигурации , но вот в чем именно она состоит я не понимаю:

appconfig-security.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> <intercept-url 
        pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/personalOffice"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />


</http>



<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="ua.java.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>
```

Консоль:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-mvc.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.java.services.SecurityService ua.java.controllers.FlowController.securityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ua.java.services.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.java.services.SecurityService ua.java.controllers.FlowController.securityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ua.java.services.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:287)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:266)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.java.services.SecurityService ua.java.controllers.FlowController.securityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ua.java.services.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ua.java.services.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ua.java.services.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:34)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:25)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 79 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' to required type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder' for property 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:474)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
... 91 more
```

Так как СтекОверфлоу не очень любит длинные посты нет возможности дать весь код проекта не ввиде ссылки на гит https://github.com/6ruceWayne/Testowiki.git

Comment: добавлять бинарные (да еще и генерируемые файлы) в репозиторий совершенно не нужно. добавьте директорию **target** в **.gitignore**

Comment: скорей всего проблема в вашей локальной конфигурации и повторить ее вряд ли получится у другого человека

Comment: эм...я не совсем понимаю что подразумевается под "локальной конфигурацией" и что мне с этим делать. Пробовал снести репозиторий и пересобирать проект , перезагружать винду , откатить обновления последней (как одно из предположений ибо как раз вчера обновился). Удаление обновлений безопастности кстати не получилось сделать. Что можно в таком случае предпринять кроме как убрать всю регистрационную часть и написать какую то другую пока не могу придумать. Кстати раскопал старую 100% рабочую в прошлом версию проекта - на ней та же самая ошибка выскочила

Comment: если в старой версии такая же ошибка, то проблема не в коде. у вас база настроена? а настройки хранятся в репозитории? а сервер приложений настроен? а настройки хранятся в репозитории? и т.д и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в Tomcat
После того как я пересоздал сервер (очистив конфигурацию конечно же) все заработало.
П.с. Томкат в топку.